# How to add an active class to a header menu without the defaut event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I'm building a Prestashop website using a theme. This theme uses jQuery and Bootstrap. So I am trying to add bootstrap active class to my navbar in order to get that active effect on my menu.

The codes are below :

```
$('.cbp-hrmenu-tab .nav-link').click(function(){
      $('.cbp-hrmenu-tab .nav-link').removeClass("activeLink");
      $(this).addClass("activeLink");
      console.log("Hello world");
});
```

The code "works", I have in my console "Hello word" when I **JUST** clicked on the menu, so do the activeLink class too, but both disappear just after the reload of the website due to my click event.

By putting an eye on other posts, I also tried with `e.preventDefault()`, now the code works, it adds the activeLink class to my menu but nothing happens anymore => no more redirection of page, no reload of the page by clicking on the menu.

```
$('.cbp-hrmenu-tab .nav-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cbp-hrmenu-tab .nav-link').removeClass("activeLink");
    $(this).addClass("activeLink");
    console.log("Hello world");
});
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: its not clear, do you want to use click or not?

Comment: Yes, i want to use click to add the "activeLink" class to the link when i am on the relative page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i just found the solution by myself :

```
var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); 
    $('.cbp-hrmenu-tab .nav-link').each(function(){
          
         if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
              $(this).addClass('activeLink');
            }
        });
```